# How to pass list data into insert statement in SQL server using python?

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python and creating a python app to insert data into the SQL server table. I'm trying it in the following way but it gives me an error.

**This is my code**

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=company_mine;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

datalist = ['KFC', ' kfc', '71 Tottenham Ct Rd', 'London', 'null', 'null', 'London']

sql_insert_query1 = """INSERT INTO company_details(company_name,contact_name,mailing_street,mailing_city,mailing_state,mailing_postal_code,mailing_country)VALUES(%s)"""

cursor1 = conn.cursor()
cursor1.executemany(sql_insert_query1, datalist)
conn.commit()
print(cursor1.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully")
```

[image: This is the error]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you only want to insert a single row in your table.  In that case, try replacing the line

```py
cursor1.executemany(sql_insert_query1, datalist)
```

with

```py
cursor1.execute(sql_insert_query1, datalist)
```

`cursor1.executemany` expects to be given a list of lists of values, and will execute the statement it has been given once for each list in the list of lists. For example, if you had two rows to insert, your `datalist` variable might look like the following (I've made up details for the second row):

```py
datalist = [
    ['KFC', ' kfc', '71 Tottenham Ct Rd', 'London', 'null', 'null', 'London'],
    ['LGN', ' lgn', '72 High Street', 'Birmingham', 'null', 'null', 'Birmingham']
]
```

If you passed this to `cursor.executemany`, it would run two `INSERT` statements, one using the values in the first list within `datalist`, and one using the values in the second list.

---

I've noticed another couple of problems with your code. Firstly, the SQL statement in `sql_insert_query1` contains only a single `%s` placeholder. You need to have one for each column. You have seven columns, so replace `VALUES(%s)` with `VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)`.

Also, I note that you are attempting to insert the string `'null'` into some of the above columns. This won't insert a SQL `NULL` value, instead, it will insert the text `null` into that column, which you might not want. Use the Python `None` value to represent a SQL `NULL` value.